# SSH not working

Tags: raspbian

I have been unable to SSH into my Pi 2 using PuTTY on my Windows 7 machine. Every time i try to login, it gives me an error "Connection refused". Can somebody please help? I use Raspbian.

Comment: *"Connection refused"* implies there is nothing listening on the port at that address.  So if the address is correct, there is probably no `sshd` running on the pi.

Answer (score 3):

it seems that package `openssh-server` isn't installed. Why don't you installing it using

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install openssh-server
```

and then to make sure it starting, please use this code

```
sudo service ssh start
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's a fresh raspbian. SSH will be enabled by default. You might wanna configure network though if you're using wifi. It should work on eth0 out of the box. Make sure Ip you're connecting is right. Also login username should be pi.

Hope it helps.